# Elementary problem in Probability

Tags: probability

A disease is spreading across the city of Rome. If the vaccine is taken, there is $ 95/100 $ probability that you won't be infected. Independently, there is $ 25/100 $ probability that you won't be infected if you go outside the city. What is the probability of avoiding the disease if you take the vaccine *and* go outside the city?

I calculated the probability of getting infected, which should correspond to the one of both the vaccine and the going outside not to work, $ (5/100)\times(75/100) $. Then I subtracted this quantity from $ 1 $ to get $ 77/80 $, and this I suppose is the answer. I have some doubts about it though, is it correct?

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret this. Is it $95/100$ if you vaccinate and _do not leave_, or in all cases where you vaccinate? Is it $25/100$ outside the city only if you do not vaccinate? What if you do neither? And what is your definition of "independent" for $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|C)$ (as opposed to $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|A)$)?

Comment: @DavidK I think "independent" in this case means that the two probabilities do not influence each other, i.e. the vaccine has 95/100 probability to work both in the city and outside, the same goes for leaving the city.

Comment: If $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ the total probabilities are independent. If $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$ then the conditional probabilities of $A$ and $B$ are independent. But here we have probability of just one event, conditioned on two other events--what's the formula that says when the two probabilities are independent?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to interpret the problem as follows.  In order to be infected, two things must happen - you must come into contact with a carrier of the disease, and your body must fail to fight off the infection.  Leaving the city lowers your chances of contact with a carrier.  Getting the vaccine lowers the chance of not fighting off the infection.  Neither precaution affects the chances of the OTHER factor occurring.  The formula is simple enough...  but since we don't know how much *difference* the precaution cause in the chances, we can't do that math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. The assumption that the actions (vaccination & leaving the city) are independent is crucial: Imagine that the vaccination works only in the city. In that case the probability of avoiding the disease after leaving the city is then 25/100 even if you are vaccinated.

Comment: That's ... pretty much the OPPOSITE of what "independent" means.  "Independent" means that the way one event works itself out does NOT affect the other events.  Hypothesizing that the precaution of leaving the city *alters* the probability of the vaccine having a protective effect in the event of an exposure?  That's the opposite of "independent".

Comment: I think Karel was showing the importance of the hypothesis of independence...I believe you misunderstood.

Comment: I may have misread that part.  I was confused by his saying "This is correct", because I don't know what "this" he's referring to.  OP's original calculations aren't correct, even if they do treat the issue of independence correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing data that you need to calculate the probability.

If we knew the probability of one who *neither takes the vaccines nor leaves the city contracting the disease*, we could answer the question.

Suppose the probability of avoiding infection if you take neither precaution is 0/100.  Then we could say "Oh, getting the vaccine reduces your chances of infection by a factor of 20" (100/100 without the vaccine, 5/100 with).

We could then apply that to the 75/100 probability of infection if your only precaution is leaving the city, and say "Those who take both precautions therefore reduce their vulnerability from 75/100 from leaving the city to 3.75/100".  Subtract that from 1, and you have the probability of avoiding the disease by taking both precautions.

But what if the chance of avoiding the infection with neither precaution was already 60/100?  Then the magnitude of the effect of both precautions is much small than we thought.  Without that missing information, we can't get the right answer.